# Unable to execute multiple commands in a sequence using exec() function of php in windows 7

Tags: php, exec

I want to execute multiple commands in a sequence using exec() function of php (OS - windows 7, XAMPP)

For example

```
<?php
      exec('command1; command2; command3; command4', $output, $return_var);
?>
```

but only two (first and last) commands execute. What can be the issue?

**UPDATED**

I want to play 5 audio files in a sequence as server-side playback (using speakers of server instead of client’s speakers). I found that solution by using Copilot of Microsoft as well as in different postss of stackoverflow.com e.g. [How to execute multiple commands in PHP exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75110609/how-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-php-exec)
i.e. `shell_exec("1.mp3 && 2.mp3 && 3.mp3 && 4.mp3 && 5.mp3");` or `exec("1.mp3 && 2.mp3 && 3.mp3 && 4.mp3 && 5.mp3");` but only two (first and last) commands execute and sometimes only one / last command executes.

Comment: Try to use code that, at least in theory, could do something. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Where did you learn that you can execute multiple commands like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple commands on a single line in a Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922224/multiple-commands-on-a-single-line-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: I want to play 5 audio files in a sequence as server-side playback (using speakers of server instead of client’s speakers).
I found that solution by using Copilot of Microsoft. 
i.e. 
shell_exec("1.mp3 && 2.mp3 && 3.mp3 && 4.mp3 && 5.mp3");
or 
exec("1.mp3 && 2.mp3 && 3.mp3 && 4.mp3 && 5.mp3");

but only two (first and last) commands execute and sometimes only one / last command executes.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided a minimal, reproducible example so it is very tough to analyse your issue. As I can see from the info you provided, in order to run multiple commands only exec() function is eligible for this not shell_exec(). Also you need to provide the path for each value. In case of xampp it is “php” by default. Like:

```
<?php
$cmd = "php 1.mp3 && php 2.mp3 && php 3.mp3 && php 4.mp3 && php 5.mp3";
exec($cmd, $output, $returnStatus);
```

And you can use the output varible for your purpose. However, calling exec() multiple times will be better for handling multiple data.

Comment: Earlier, only first or “first and last audio” were playing but after configuring VLC Media Player as follow now all audio files are playing
"Tools" >> "Preferences." >> "All" under "Show Settings" >> "Playlist" >> "Play and Exit"
And PHP code is……
exec("1.mp3 && 2.mp3 && 3.mp3 && 4.mp3 && 5.mp3");

Anyway, thanks to all of you………..

Answer (score -1):

Earlier, only first audio file or first and last audio files were playing but after configuring VLC Media Player as follow now all audio files are playing.

"Tools" >> "Preferences." >> "All" under "Show Settings" >> "Playlist" >> "Play and Exit"

And PHP code is

```
exec("1.mp3 && 2.mp3 && 3.mp3 && 4.mp3 && 5.mp3");
```

Anyway, thanks to all of you.